What are these waves appearing in my photos?
I just purchased a Canon EF 75-300 lens which is then attached to a Beastgrip (MK3) DOF adapter, which is mounted to my iPhone 15 Pro.
My phone's camera doesn't have these waves, so I know it isn't the phone.
The lens and the adapter are brand new. So I don't know if this is due to the adapter or the lens. But I'm also not aware if this a common issue among zoom lenses.
If anyone has info on what might cause these waves. It does seem like they don't appear until I'm using the maximum zoom on the lens.
In the photo, you can see some sort of wave effect in the sky and along the sky-rise and it's antenna.


This almost looks like aliasing.  Did you shoot through a window screen?

@davolfman Nope, I was standing outside on the roof.

Unless this is the raw image, processed with a known demosaicing app, I would ascribe that to the in-phone post-processing. In particular, anything that could be done to reduce camera shake could be foiled by the unexpected focal length.

"I'm also not aware if this a common issue among zoom lenses" Well, have you ever seen it in any other photo before? I've no idea what the cause is, but you are using the phone and the lens for purposes entirely different to what they were designed for. I would have low expectations of any such setup working successfully.

Helpful. Thanks. @osullic

Not sure what you mean by "waves". I see banding in the clouds (due to limited dynamic range AKA bit-depth of camera), strong chromatic aberration (e.g., edges of building on right) and strong vignetting in corners, though.
